# Rails 7 - Stimulus Controller connection or/and syntax error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs, hotwire

My controller:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";
import consumer from "channels/consumer";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["users", "roomId"];

  connect() {
    console.log("");
    this.subscription = consumer.subscriptions.find("RoomChannel");
  }

};
```

My room_channel.js:

```
import consumer from "channels/consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("RoomChannel", {



  connected() {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
    console.log("Connected to rooms channel");

  }

},
```

My HTML:

```
<div data-controller="room">
   <!-- get data -->
</div>
```

Result in console.log():

```
Error connecting controller

TypeError: consumer.subscriptions.find is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, consumer.subscriptions doesn't have the 'find' method, but it has several different methods: ['create', 'add', 'remove', 'reject', 'forget', 'findAll', 'reload', 'notifyAll', 'notify', 'subscribe', 'confirmSubscription', 'sendCommand']

You probably wanted to use the method findAll, but don't forget that this method accepts full channel identifier

```
this.subscription = consumer.subscriptions.findAll(
      '{"channel":"RoomChannel","room":"Best Room"}')
```